# Illegal String Offset While Passing Form Data

Tags: php

I'm trying to setup form data for cURL with a multidimensional array and having some trouble. My code is below:

```
$fields = array(
    'full_name' => 'John Doe',
    'email' => 'name@example.com'
    'extra' => array(
            'IP' => '10.10.10.10',
            'Platform' => 'Macintosh'
        )
);

$delimiter = '-------------' . $boundary;
$data = '';

foreach ($fields as $name => $content) {
    if(is_array($content)) {
        foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
            $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "\r\n"
                . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name[$key] . "\"\r\n\r\n"
                . $value . "\r\n";
        }
    } else {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "\r\n"
            . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . "\"\r\n\r\n"
            . $content . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Illegal string offset 'IP'
Illegal string offset 'Platform'
```

How would I pass `name=extra['IP']` and `name=extra['Platform']` without the errors? Or, am I doing this incorrectly? Thanks much.

Comment: `$name[$key]` should just be `$key`

Comment: Then, I would not have an array named `extra` on the receiving end of cURL

Comment: That is the source of your `Illegal string offset` errors. Without understanding what your expected output is meant to look like it's impossible to offer any more advice.

Comment: My expected output is an array named `extra` which I can process on the cURL endpoint.

Comment: `"{$name}[{$key}]"`…?

Answer (score 0):

Form submission formats doesn't support nested (multi-dimensional) arrays.In order to process those data you have to do either serialize array inside array that is:

```
'extra' => serialize(array(
        'IP' => '10.10.10.10',
        'Platform' => 'Macintosh'
    ))
```

or change data in other format for instance JSON, which allows nested arrays.

for your reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99108

Comment: @dario-zadro have you tried this? I am getting down vote don't know why, this is mentioned in the documentation as well.

Comment: Hi and thank you. The comment above form @deceze worked for me. I upvoted you because your solution would work, just not in my case.